# Is it possible to load a Handlebars template via Ajax?

Tags: ember.js, handlebars.js

I would like to load additional templates on the fly. Is it possible?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You can register new templates in `Ember.TEMPLATES`. They will then be available to views.

An excerpt from my code (jQuery Ajax handler):

```
success: function(data) {
  $(data).filter('script[type="text/x-handlebars"]').each(function() {
    templateName = $(this).attr('data-template-name');
    Ember.TEMPLATES[templateName] = Ember.Handlebars.compile($(this).html());
  });
}
```

That's it.

Comment: Mike...would you mind wrapping that code up into a larger package so that we can see the lifecycle? How are you storing the external template? What's it's filetype? Are you loading it with a get or getJSON?

Comment: I retrieve the template content from the results of a `get` call, containing HTML entities, as they would arrive in a plain standard page response.

Comment: This is a [my]world saving solution :) Thx!

Comment: IS this generally considered good practice? OR should all views be loaded on first page load?

Comment: Generally speaking, all the templates are loaded as a single preprocessed bunch of data, but there are corner cases when this code can be useful.

Answer (score 7):

I was just looking for the same thing and am about to have a play with the snippet below

credit: borismus on github https://gist.github.com/2165681

```
<script>
/*
 * Loads a handlebars.js template at a given URL. Takes an optional name, in which     case,
 * the template is added and is reference-able via templateName.
 */
function loadTemplate(url, name, callback) {
  var contents = $.get(url, function(templateText) {
    var compiledTemplate = Ember.Handlebars.compile(templateText);
    if (name) {
      Ember.TEMPLATES[name] = compiledTemplate
    } else {
      Ember.View.create({ template: compiledTemplate }).append();
    }
    if (callback) {
      callback();
    }
  });
}
</script>
```

Comment: Interesting, indeed. It's more a kind of primitive, to load a single template. My previous solution allows any number of templates loading *(more appropriated to my need)*.

Comment: I see. I do actually quite like idea of more a multi-template 'include' file, just to get some noise out of the HTML file and not create too many request. Good call

Answer (score 1):

I am using requirejs along with text plugin to load handlebar templates dynamically.

r.js optimizer will compile the handlerbar template to text file, which can be loaded easily using requirejs or even ajax