# Ember reload layout scripts

Tags: javascript, jquery, ember.js

Exist some method to reloading a script layout wiht emberjs using ajax html called?

Example

1. Page load all the information
2. Press a button which looking with ajax a html (including a script handlerbar) and load it on a div element
3. Take that layout view and used it with a view.

**NOW** I Just can use the layout view that i created before to call the emberjs object. but i need created too many layout and i want to loading with each request from the user.

Thanks i u can help me

Answer (score 0):

I had a very similar need (dynamic template loading).

Maybe a part of your solution is here: [Is it possible to load a Handlebars template via Ajax?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9469235/90741)

Comment: did you have any success? I'm interested in your final solution.