# Can't get template portion to render in Ember.js

Tags: ember.js, handlebars.js

I am having some issues getting Ember.js to pick up and render a handlebars template file. I get the following error in my browser's debug console:

> Error: <(subclass of Welcome.LoginView):ember166> - Unable to find template "login_view".

I have the following code in emberjs code in my app.js file:

```
Welcome = Ember.Application.create();

Welcome.LoginView = Ember.View.extend({
  templateName: 'login_view'
});
```

I also have the following snippet in my index.html file:

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars">
  {{view Welcome.LoginView}}
</script>
```

Finally, relative to the app.js file I have the file templates/login_view.handlebars, which contains the template contents to render:

```
<form class="form-inline">
  <fieldset>
    <input type="text" name="email" placeholder="email address">
    <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="password">
    <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Sign In</button>
    <!-- ... -->
  </fieldset>
</form>
```

The error seems to indicate that it can't locate the handlebars template. When I look at the generated HTML I don't see the above form on the page.

Can anyone shed some light on what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 4):

From your question I assume that you are NOT using some tools which precompile a handlebars template for you. Ember looks for templates in the `Ember.TEMPLATES` array–it does not automatically look for templates located at `templates/` and ending with `.handlebars`. Without a build step that compiles the templates for you, you have to do this on your own.

This may sound complicated but it's as easy as the following:

```js
Ember.TEMPLATES["login_view"] = Ember.Handlebars.compile('TEMPLATE CODE');
```

You have to make sure that this template definition occurs **before** you want to use it.

---

Another solution would be to inline your template into your `index.html` and add a `data-template-name="login_view"` attribute to the script tag:

```html
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="login_view">
  <form class="form-inline">
    <!-- ... -->
  </form>
</script>
```

However, if your project has numerous templates then I would suggest you adopt a build tool that does the first option for you.

---

Related question: [Is it possible to load a Handlebars template via Ajax?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9469235/65542)