# ember.js - common functionality shared across controllers - popups, notifications

Tags: ember.js, code-reuse

i've red quite a of lot tuts and articles on ember.js and made some basic stuffs - some sanbox and test things, complete login screen with many outlets, actions, ajax and so on... but I am now facing one problem.

Ember.js is for "Single Page Application" and I did not found a way (yet?) how can I make and **share** basic functionality across more "ember apps"/parts?

I have some backend and then some modules (users, files, news,...) and each is made by classic:

```
App = Ember.Application.Create()
```

But I need to have some shared functionality and I dont want to repeat in at each app - I want to be able to show some **notification** - once from user app then from files app and so on. Or to have **unified modal window**, or function that check some things in background on server and push updates to notifications area that is running on each of those app parts...

How should I solve it? Is there any way of extending base App? or have to separates App on one page that communicates to each other? I've also read something about Ember namespaces but I am not sure if it is the right thing and how to user it :(

note: Each module (dashboard, users, files,...) is loaded as new page (complete html, new scripts,...), but module itself work as a SPA and on AJAX.

Ember.js has awesome documentation but real word example articles on how to use it are showing slowly and I had no lucky finding some tut/article on solving this problem in real world.

Answer (score 1):

You can set another module and run it as another ember app in the same page, define the root element of the apps

```
var AppNotification = Ember.Application.create({
  rootElement: '#notifications'
});

var AppUsers = Ember.Application.create({
  rootElement: '#users'
});
```

So you need to associate the main apps to a div (#dashboard,#users,#files) and another div for the notifications.

I don't know if it it possible to communicate from one app to another, this is very advanced, but you can investigate ember instrumentation...http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Instrumentation.html

Good Luck

Comment: oh, I havent seen this before :) thanks will try it. How then I can call for example the notification controller from within user controller? with using?

Comment: I did some research and should I then use: _App = Ember.Appl.Create()_ and _App.Notifications = Ember.ObjectController.extend({...})_ in some js file that is loaded everywhere. And then have another file where I will have _App.Users = Ember.ObjectController.extend({...})_ ? Is this a proper way how to make it? If so I think I am starting getting it :) thanks!

Comment: nicer code in my mirrored question here: [discuss.emberjs.com](http://discuss.emberjs.com/t/common-functionality-shared-accros-controllers-popups-notifications/3389/2)

Comment: I edited the answer because the code you posted in [discuss.emberjs.com](http://discuss.emberjs.com/t/common-functionality-shared-accros-controllers-popups-notifications/3389/2) is not correct IMHO

Answer (score 1):

I just remembered (beer enligthment) other different way I've read months ago... [load async code from the router](https://gist.github.com/machty/5647589) [JSBin example](http://jsbin.com/axarop/59/edit)

You can have your notification js stuff  and take the templates using [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9482897/1806037)