# How to include curly brackets in innerhtml function

Tags: javascript, ember.js, handlebars.js

Hi I'm trying to use the following function:

```
<script>
$(function(){
 document.getElementById("alert").innerHTML="<button {{action 'alert'}}>i</button>";
 });
</script>
```

However the html is rendered as:

```
<button 'alert'}}="" {{action="">i</button>
```

I've searched and can't find a solution, any help appreciated.

Comment: use `\\` that is skip character in javascript strings

Comment: I do not think your templating code works that way...

Comment: You're trying to inject invalid HTML code. If you want it to be a real button, you simply can't do it like that, at least not without some unpleasant surprises depending on the HTML engine. If you want it as plain text data (not as HTML tag) you should replace `<` by `&lt;` and `>` by `&gt;`.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, the templating code is from emberjs, they example they give is <button {{action 'contract'}}>Contract</button>, from http://emberjs.com/guides/templates/actions/

Comment: Yes that is a template...are you trying to change the template on the fly? AKA http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9469235/is-it-possible-to-load-a-handlebars-template-via-ajax

Comment: Not necessarily change the template on the fly, my model returns some text, I want to include a button that calls an action which will display a definition of the text.

Comment: I would happily include the code in the model detail, however the result is the same, so I tried this.

Comment: Ok my problem is I'm trying to inject template code after the template is rendered.  So I guess my question then is how do I call an action from html?

Answer (score -1):

You can either escape characters by using the slash notation

```
\{
```

or you can use their unicode value to get around parsing special characters.  Here is a good chart:

http://www.hardweb.com.au/XHTMLnumericalcharacterreferencecode1to999javascript.html

Comment: I've tried the back slash but the result is the same, I'll try the link, thanks

Comment: i understand that you are attempting to created a templated ember button on the fly.  i'm wondering that even if you got the element added to the document as you wish, would ember have already parsed the DOM and performed it's magic?  Perhaps there is a method for creating dynamic buttons with ember that's better than a string added to the document.

Comment: It's not necessary to add on the fly, I'd be happy to push this into the store.  Essentially, the model displays some text, some of the words need a definition, so I want to include a button that calls an action next to the word needing definition, this will trigger an alert with the definition. Simple really, what I need to know is why the code is being trashed as shown in my first post.